# Elegant way to handle missing argument using ArgResults

Tags: dart

Suppose:

```
var p = new ArgParser();
p.addOption('query');
```

Is there a way using [ArgResults](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/args/ArgResults.html) to determine whether user failed to supply --query argument without catching the ArgumentException?

```
$ dart myprogram.dart --query
Unhandled exception:
FormatException: Missing argument for "query".
```

I tried:

```
results['query'] != null
```

but get the same exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The [ArgParser](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/args/ArgParser.html) always throws a `FormatException` on [parse](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/args/ArgParser.html#parse) when the user does not provide the expected arguments.